# Depended consumers - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have table A and Table B. First I create an entity in table A and then in table B.

So I have Consumer A which listens to table A and I have Consumer B which is dependent on Consumer A and listens to table B.
Consumer A saves a dto into Redis and after that Consumer B tries to get the dto by an identifier, but sometimes Consumer B receives an event before the logic in Consumer A has been finished.
So basically I think building a retry mechanism for this type of scenario.

Comment: Look into using Saga patterns. This isn't something Kafka solves out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to put event to Redis from Consumer? Can't this be done by producer before it produces the event? If you can't see below:

You have ordering problem, Kafka can solve it when events are in the same partition forcing order of order consumption. For that events must be produced in correct order (first DTO then another event). This should be the case when second event contains first event's object ID.

If you can use single topic for those events, and correlate events by the same key - for example DTO ID, you will ensure order of events and will not have the described problem. You will end up with single topic and single consumer group.

If you cannot change two input topics, you can use Kafka Streams and join two topics into single object with all required data.

If you cannot do any of above, you have to keep state:

1. you can keep it in Kafka and reply - but this may have very high performance impact on your application
2. you can reply through another topic - for example using https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template
3. store data in database/file and process it on schedule or using Redis pubsub
4. many other options depending on your requirements